# Why would I want to use Array Types instead of standard arrays?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I am learning TypeScript. I came across the documentation about Array types where once can declare an interface as:

```
interface INumberList {
  [index: number]: number
}

// then use it
let numbers: INumberList = [1, 2, 3];
```

So my question is, what is the advantage of the above array type when I could use regular arrays or typed arrays like:

```
// regular arrays
let numbers: number[] = [1, 2, 3];

// or
let numbers: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sample there is no advantage of using such interface. In fact you narrowing down the available properties and methods of the array object to only one indexer from your interface.

The common usage I find for such interfaces as above is to define a 'map' like objects. For example:

```
/**
 * String key to any value map
 */
export interface INameValueMap<T>
{
    [key: string]: T;
}
```

Then later somewhere in your code:

```
private m_changedRequisites: INameValueMap<boolean>;
```

And here you have nice typed access to your map:

```
this.m_changedRequisites = {};
//...
this.m_changedRequisites["someRequisiteName"] = true;
```

Hope this helps.